# Project is missing required library: 'forms-1.3.0.jar' and 'miglayout15-swing.jar'

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I did a SVN checkout on a Java project in which the devs used WindowBuilder Pro to develop a GUI application - however, the devs mentioned that they didn't use any third party libraries (outside of the Java SDK - Swing and AWT). However, in the problems view of Eclipse is see three errors:

Project 'Projectname' is missing required library: 'forms-1.3.0.jar'
Project 'Projectname' is missing required library: 'miglayout15-swing.jar'
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

**Compiling ('javac') the entry point class (main()) from the command line and then running it with 'java' successfully runs the program.**

Any ideas why those errors pop up in Eclipse and how I can resolve the issue?

EDIT: Here is the .project content

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>Projectname</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Why not just add the JARs to the build path?

Comment: I don't want to get something that's not explicitly needed for deployment. Why would it run on the cmd and not in Eclipse?

Comment: It's likely from the command line that the 3rd party jars have being included within the main jars class path manifest entry.  If it doesn't compile, then it won't run. Those libraries will be required not only to compile the application, but also run it...

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn do you use ant/maven to build from command line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out WindowBuilder Pro inserted unneeded dependencies on the .classpath file.

Comment: How do did you find out they're unneeded: because it runs from the command line?

Comment: The project is not compiled into a jar.